# What is source in the Spring's ApplicationEvent?

Tags: java, spring, events

In Spring Framework classes that represent an event to be published by the `ApplicationEventPublisher` and listened to by the `@EventListener` are
`EventObject <- ApplicationEvent <- PayloadApplicationEvent`.

My question is what is the non-nullable `source` in the initial `EventObject` constructor and all derived subclasses constructors?

Javadocs give a rather vague explanation that it is
*"the object upon which the Event in question initially occurred"*.

Is it an associated domain entity or publisher service or something else?

Additionally, I am confused why is it required at all if `@EventListener` states that
*"Events can be ApplicationEvent instances as well as arbitrary objects"*?

Answer (score 3):

I understand `source` to be the where the event is created. For example, a `@Service` that processes a web request received from a `@Controller`. Therefore, when you call `ApplicationEventPublisher.publishEvent()` the source parameter to the `ApplicationEvent` event is `this`, the service.

```java
public class AwesomeEvent extends ApplicationEvent {
    private final String howAwesome;

    public AwesomeEvent(Object source, String howAwesome) {
        super(source);
        this.howAwesome = howAwesome;
    }
}

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor // because, lazy
public class AwesomeService {
    private final ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher;

    public void awesomeMethod() {
        // Do superhero awesome stuff
        eventPublisher.publishEvent(new AwesomeEvent(this, "Extremely"));
    }
}
```

Comment: How passing "this" is useful in application event? Does spring use this internally? Doesn't passing this would make it heavy object?

Answer (score -3):

Just show some code to you. Look at the getApplicationContext() method.

```
public abstract class ApplicationContextEvent extends ApplicationEvent {

public ApplicationContextEvent(ApplicationContext source) {
    super(source);
}

public final ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
    return (ApplicationContext) getSource();
}
```